# pass variable to segmented control's action

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a segment control that when one of the segments is clicked I want to pass variables (two integers to be specific) to the segmented control's action.  How do I modify the below code to do so?  I know how to go to the segment action but I don't know how to pass variables to it. I know this is probably obj-C 101 but I'm stumped.  Thanks for your help.

```
[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

.
.
.
// segment action
- (void) segmentAction:(id)sender {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a way to do it. No method on UIControl takes a UserInfo dictionary or a NSInvocation object.  Your best bet will probably just set the values in the action method based on the selectedSegmentIndex.

Answer (score 0):

As i understood, you can do it through @property directive as you can do 2 integer properties and assign them when a segment is clicked by the UIView the segment control in. It's jus a workaround solution .

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger  a,b;
@synthesize a,b;
```